# django: Cannot get group name while querying for users

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get some values from the users table combined with the group name in the same query, but the group name is always `None`.

```
class UsersView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = dict()
        users = User.objects.select_related().all()
        context['users'] = users.values('last_login', 'username', 'email', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'groups__name')
        return render_to_response('users.html',
                                  context,
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```